# How to send excel as email attachment using openpyxl without saving [On The Fly]

Tags: python, linux, django, email-attachments, openpyxl

I have been trying to send excel as email attachment using openpyxl without saving [On The Fly] in Django

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking ... where is your code that you are having a problem with, what exactly is the problem you are experiencing ... please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 17):

You can save your workbook object to a BytesIO instance (from io import BytesIO)

```
output = BytesIO()
workbook.save(output)
```

You can then use the Django EmailMessage class to create your email and attach your BytesIO object as a file as the second argument.

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
    ['bcc@example.com'],
    reply_to=['another@example.com'],
    headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
)

email.attach('file.xlsx', output.getvalue() , 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of sending an excel file via email.

```
from io import BytesIO

import xlwt
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def send_excel_email():
    excelfile = BytesIO()

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheetname')

    ws.write(0, 0, 'Firstname')
    ws.write(0, 1, 'Surname')
    ws.write(1, 0, 'Hans')
    ws.write(1, 1, 'Muster')

    wb.save(excelfile)

    email = EmailMessage()
    email.subject = 'This subject'
    email.body = 'This context'
    email.from_email = 'from@example.com'
    email.to = ['your_email@gmail.com']
    email.attach('test_file.xls', excelfile.getvalue(), 'application/ms-excel')
    email.send()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it with Django 2 , Python 3 and openxl

```
from io import BytesIO

output = BytesIO() # Create a file like object in memory
wb_object.save(output) # Write my workbook object into that memory

# Setup my email
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, "", from_email, to_email, cc=cc, bcc=bcc)

# Attach the excel file with a name, the actual attachment , and a MIMEtype.
msg.attach('my_invoice.xlsx', output.getvalue(), 'application/vnd.ms-excel')

#The content here is the email content in its body and its type which is just text.
msg.attach_alternative(content, "text/html")

# Now send it .
msg.send()
```