# adding an email notification in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying a timesheet project. I am using Django rest-framework and using Postgres as my database. My client requested me this (If a user already existed in the database or a new user is creating their account an email should be triggered when the post option was submitted in rest API).

**models.py**

```
from django.http import  HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, response
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch import  receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db.models import signals
import datetime

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage 




    

class User(models.Model):
    
    CHOICES= (
    ('manager','Manager'),
      ('hr', 'HR'),
     ('hr manager','HR Manager'),
     ('trainee','Trainee')
)

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    joiningDate=models.DateTimeField(max_length=8)
    userrole=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES,null=True)
    

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname 


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.TextField()
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    endDate=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    Submitted_by=models.ForeignKey(default=None,related_name="SubmittedBy",to='User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ApprovedBy=models.ForeignKey(default=None,related_name="ApprovedBy",to='User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date=models.DateField()
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
    
    
class Client(models.Model):
    clientname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comapny=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=25,default=None)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.clientname
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.db.models import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from.models import User,Project,Timesheet,Client    



class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields ='__all__'
       
        password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True)
        
        
class ProjectSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model= Project
        fields= '__all__'
        
        

class TimesheetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model= Timesheet
        fields= '__all__'
        
        
class ClientSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model=Client
        fields=  '__all__'
```

**viewset.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from.import models
from.import serializers


class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset=models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.UserSerializers
    

class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset=models.Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.ProjectSerializers
    
class TimesheetViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset=models.Timesheet.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.TimesheetSerializers
    
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset=models.Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.ClientSerializers
```

**router.py**

```
from App.viewsets import ClientViewSet, UserViewset,ProjectViewSet,TimesheetViewset
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('User',UserViewset)
router.register('Project',ProjectViewSet)
router.register('Timesheet',TimesheetViewset)
router.register('Client',ClientViewSet)
```

I am new to Django.

Answer (score 1):

It's really an important question. I just did work like this a few days ago.
I am adding according to my work.

in your serializers.py you can do this.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class TimesheetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model= Timesheet
    fields= '__all__'
def create(self, validated_data):
    timesheet = Timesheet.objects.create(**validated_data)
    send_mail(
        'Timesheet {} has been created'.format(timesheet.pk),
        'A new timesheet has been created . DATA: {}'.format(
        validated_data), #mail_body
        'noreply@email.com', #from_email
        ['user@email.com'], #to_email
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

and you need to set email sending method in settings.py

```
#settings.py
#for sending testing emails you can use mailtrap.io as well that is almost same as smtp server
#for smtp
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

#for sending emails to terminal
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

You can use **celery** for sending emails asynchronously.

but at first, you should do this to check.
[Here is the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/) for sending email.
it's really great.

and as I mentioned above about mailtrap so here is the link [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/)

And you can follow this tutorial for setup email [here is the link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setup-sending-email-in-django-project/)

Still, if you have any kind of confusion let me know.
**Thanks a lot.**

Comment: Solution is correct, I did used something like this in my recent project

Comment: thanks and I will follow your suggestion as well. thanks

Comment: @Polymath is there any way to attach an excel doc and send it.

Comment: @ZoroD yes you can

Comment: Can you help me with that...@Anny

Comment: @ZoroD can u plz have a look into it 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396268/12499225

Comment: @Anny hii...Tried what you sad but not able to grasp it exactly...Can you  help me with this

Comment: @Anny .I have sent our code which you have answered to my client...So can't change another code and he's having with our existing one...So kindly guide me to add an attachment functionality in our existing code

Comment: @ZoroD hey. So sorry for the late response. 
can you tell me the issue you are facing.
I mean do you want me to tell you that how to attach a file in this mailing way?

Comment: @ZoroD Hello 
I think EmailMessage is enough for you
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/
plz follow this link at the bottom. I think this will be enough helpful
still if you need any help let me know 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is same as [Anny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12499225/anny) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845795/17951403)

The solutions was:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class TimesheetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model= Timesheet
    fields= '__all__'
def create(self, validated_data):
    timesheet = Timesheet.objects.create(**validated_data)
    send_mail(
        'Timesheet {} has been created'.format(timesheet.pk),
        'A new timesheet has been created . DATA: {}'.format(
        validated_data), #mail_body
        'noreply@email.com', #from_email
        ['user@email.com'], #to_email
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

The only issue with that solution is, it will increase the loading time.
Alternately you can do is use threading and divert the email sending process to a different thread

You can do it by creating new file named `utils.py`:

```
import threading
from django.core import mail

class EmailThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, subject, plain_message, from_email, to_email, html_message):
        self.subject = subject
        self.plain_message = plain_message
        self.from_email = from_email
        self.to_email = to_email
        self.html_message = html_message
        super(EmailThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        mail_send = mail.send_mail(self.subject, self.plain_message, self.from_email, [self.to_email], html_message=self.html_message)
        print('mail send successfully ', mail_send)
```

and in your `serializer.py`:

```
from .utlis.py import *

class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def create(self, validate_data):
        subject = <subject_here>
        plan_message = <plain_message_in_string>
        from_email = <from_mail>
        to_email = <email_you_want_to_send_to>
        html_message = <if you want to include any html template for mail>
        EmailThread(subject, plain_message, from_email, to_email, html_message).start()
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
    
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields ='__all__'
       
        password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True)
```

and in your settings.py add the following:

```
# EMAIL CONFIGURATION
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<email_user_here>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<password_here>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Hii @Polymath thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I'm having a doubt, actually the user may be anyone they'll be having different email ids. `to_email = <email_you_want_to_send_to> ` in this line we can't know give particular user. mail right! .  So how the random person will be getting the mail and My Hr must have a notification the user has logged in and my last doubt is what are the things I need to change in settings.py

Comment: Hi Zoro, I have edited the post to solve your settings.py issue, can you repeat your doubt so that I can understand better before giving any solutions

Comment: Hii @Polymath The code worked fine thanks but I'm having an issue `to_email = <email_you_want_to_send_to> ` in this we need to give an email, right? and I tried giving a sample email and it worked perfectly...But the user maybe unknown and will have different emails So here how do I send mail without knowing the user email id .

Comment: And @Polymath while giving post call, the call is not getting updated in the database but when commenting the codes and running the server the models field gets updated

Comment: Sorry for the data not getting saved issue, I have updated the code, simply just replace return statement with return User.objects.create(**validated_data) & yes regarding your doubt you can access any field from serializer by validated_data["name_of_the_field"], here name_of_the_field = email, so you can get user's email by this method

Comment: Thanks bro @Polymath Code worked perfectly and DB was connected successfully

Comment: If the liked the solution and it works then please upvote so the community can review the answer is working on the given question, thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used celery later to send email. and I will definitely add your suggestion in my code. thanks a lot